# Why a simple linked list reverse function always return the last node instead of the first

Tags: c++, c

I have written a simple reverse function for the linked list, shown below:

```cpp
typedef struct _NODE
{
    int data;
    _NODE *next;

}NODE;

void print(NODE *head)
{
    NODE *start;
    start = head;
    while (start)
    {
        printf("%d ", start->data);
        start = start->next;
    }
}
NODE* reverse(NODE *head)
{
    NODE *prev = NULL;
    NODE *curr = head;

    while (curr)
    {
        NODE *temp = curr->next;
        curr->next = prev;
        prev = curr;
        curr = temp;
    }
    head = prev;

    return head;

}
int main()
{
    NODE *head = new NODE;
    NODE *node1 = new NODE;
    NODE *node2 = new NODE;

    head->data = 1;
    node1->data = 2;
    node2->data = 3;

    head->next = node1;
    node1->next = node2;
    node2->next = NULL;

    reverse(head);

    print(head);


    getchar();

    delete head;
    delete node1;
    delete node2;
    head = NULL;
    node1 = NULL;
    node2 = NULL;

    return 1;

}
```

I found the output will always be `1`. My question is why does the head pointer after the `reverse` function always point to the node with value `1`. I have already assigned the previous pointer to the head pointer in the `reverse` function.

But if I change below, the output became correct.

```
reverse(head);
```

To

```
head = reverse(head);
```

Comment: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/430958)

Comment: If you wrote this code then surely you have an idea why `reverse` was written to return a value.

Comment: The function returns the new head. It does not (cannot) modify the value of the variable whose value you passed to it. (There is nothing special about pointers.)

Comment: You can change the name of the parameter in reverse to head_copy

Comment: `_NODE` identifier is reserved to the language implementation. You should rename your class. How about `ಠ_ಠNode`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `head` variable in the `reverse` function is not the same variable as the `head` variable in the `main` function.

Assigning to the `head` variable in `reverse` does not change the value of the `head` variable in `main`.